# How do you work on an AWS machine in kaggle?

Tags: amazon-ec2, machine-learning, kaggle

I want to work on an aws machine for a kaggle competition. While working on my own pc i have Anaconda installed, pycharm. 
How do i set it up on an AWS machine? 
Do i need to install the tools each time i log in the AWS machine.

What is the recommended way for this cases?
I thought of running a jupyter notebook instance on the remote machine, and connect to that web page via my local machine. 
What are the pitfalls to be expected?

Answer (score 1):

You need to launch an EC2 instance in AWS and connect it through SSH to run your algorithms. The following link can help you further.
http://www.grant-mckinnon.com/?p=6

Answer (score 1):

In these cases using Docker images helps the best in encapsulating the environment. Kaggle also uses docker to create environments for kernels. You can install Docker from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04). You can pull the docker image using following command,

```
docker pull datmo/kaggle:python
```

After this, you can run containers using this image and mount necessary files in order to run the same environment.

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8888:8888  -v ~/.:/home/  datmo/kaggle:python 'jupyter notebook'
```

You can also use [datmo](https://datmo.com/) CLI in order to easily setup environment and also version control your machine learning models.